# Display UIImagePickerViewController for uiimagepickercontrollersourcetypephotolibrary from UIActionSheet in IPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller, uiactionsheet

I have a `UIActionSheet` which has options to choose image from Camera or photo library. For this I took **imagePickerViewController**. For camera it works absolutely fine. But not for photo library.

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex == 0) 
    {

        imgController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imgController.allowsEditing = YES;
        imgController.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;   
        imgController.delegate=self;
        [self presentModalViewController:imgController animated:YES];

    } 
    else if (buttonIndex == 1) 
    {

        if ([self.popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
            [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
            [popoverController release];
        } else {
            if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
                 UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
            {
                UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
                [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
                imagePicker.delegate = self;
                imagePicker.sourceType =
                UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

                self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                          initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];

                self.popoverController.delegate = self;

                [self.popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(500, 500)];

                [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:self.view.frame 
                                                          inView:self.view
                                        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                                                        animated:YES];


                [imagePicker release];
            }
        }


    } 

}
```

On touching photo library option a small **popupViewController** is created on top of view but it is very small. Why the **popupViewController** is too small? Is there some other way to for displaying `UIImagePickerViewController` for `uiimagepickercontrollersourcetypephotolibrary`?

Comment: change the presentPopoverFromRect size according you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out this example

```
   CGRect popoverRect = [self.view convertRect:[self.view frame] 
                                       fromView:[self.view superview]];

    popoverRect.size.width = MIN(popoverRect.size.width, 80) ; 
    popoverRect.origin.x  = popoverRect.origin.x+150; 

    [self.popoverController 
     presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect 
     inView:self.view 
     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft
     animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the rect you pass in should be smaller, not the size of the whole view:

```
CGRect popFrom = CGRectMake (CGPointMake(50,50),10,10);
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popFrom 
                                                          inView:self.view
                                        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                                                        animated:YES];
```

Comment: Haha, late night error, thanks for pointing it out...I've fixed it, glad I was of some help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try by not setting the `PopoverContentSize` for `UIImagePickerViewController` presented in the popover - I think it's taken care of automatically! Also, the `CGRect` in `presentPopoverFromRect:` seems to be incorrect as you're passing the `view`'s frame which translates to the popover pointing roughly to the centre of the screen. You might want to set that to the frame of the button that presented the `UIActionSheet`!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 imagePickerController.delegate = self;
 imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
 [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
```